# Collection View Context Menu

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в контекстное меню добавить переключатель или другой подобный элемент, если да то как? В документации нашел три класса UIMenu, UIAction и UICommand но как запихать в них элемент типа UISwitch не пойму.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не получится. Если нужен свитер, придется пилить кастомную менюху.
Или обновлять кнопки в меню после переключения (так делает эпл).